# LaTex code inside gnuplot labels

Tags: cross-referencing, gnuplot, gnuplottex

I would like if could I use LaTex code inside gnuplot labels or even inside graph key, I'm using `gnuplottex` package and I like to make cross-referencing inside this labels, this is my MWE

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx,gnuplottex,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
y = x^2 \label{eq:x2}
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{gnuplot}[scale=1.3, terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions=color dashed]
        set samples 50000
        set grid
        unset key
        set xrange [-3:1]
        set yrange [0:20]
        set label "$y=x^2$" at -0.5,1
        set label "\eqref{eq:x2}" at -0.5,3

        p x**2
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption{\eqref{eq:x2} parabolic curve} \label{fig:FermDistNorm}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Maybe gnuplottex is not enough to do this. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In gnuplot, the backslash is used as an escape character, as it is in LaTeX. So, when latex calls gnuplot, gnuplot gobbles up the backslash, and latex is asked to process the title 'eqref{eq:x2}', which just means that the braces are removed, and you end up with 'eqrefeq:x2' as your label (in a nice font).

The solution is to stop gnuplot from interpreting the backslash as an escape character, which you can do by putting an extra backslash before `eqref`, or using single, rather than double, quotes. See pages 24-25 of the [gnuplot 5 manual](http://www.gnuplot.info) for more details.

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx,gnuplottex,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}                                                                                                                                     
y = x^2 \label{eq:x2}                                                                                                                                
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{gnuplot}[scale=1.3, terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions=color dashed]
        set samples 50000
        set grid
        unset key
        set xrange [-3:1]
        set yrange [0:20]
        set label "$y=x^2$" at -0.5,1
        set label "\\eqref{eq:x2}" at -0.5,3  #or use '\eqref{eq:x2}'

        p x**2
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption{\eqref{eq:x2} parabolic curve} \label{fig:FermDistNorm}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) but now I don't know why when I do cross referencing the key it is horizontally oversized http://imgur.com/a/d1kZA

Comment: I have to go offline for two hours, but if you post another question with an example that shows this effect, I will look at it later (unless someone else fixes it first).

Comment: I've accepted as workaround `set key box width -15` to reduce it.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it's helpful, here's a version that uses [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), and there's no need to use `shell-escape`

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}                                                                                                                                     
y = x^2 \label{eq:x2}                                                                                                                                
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-3,xmax=1,
      ymin=0,ymax=20,
      xtick={-3,-2.5,...,1},
      grid=major,
      ]
      \addplot[-,blue,thick,domain=-3:1]{x^2} node[pos=0.9,anchor=south] {$y=x^2$ \eqref{eq:x2}}; 
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{using pgfplots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```